# Get top three items with unique value from dictionary

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary

```
dict1 = {'apple':50,'banana':20,'orange':50,'peach':20,
     'mango':10}
```

I know how to get the top three items using the following:

```
def test(x):
    return x[1]

sorted(dict1.items(), key=test, reverse=True)[:3]
```

and I got

```
 [('apple', 50), ('orange', 50), ('banana', 20)]
```

But notice that apple and orange are of the same value which is 50.

How do I modify the code to get output like this?

```
[('apple', 50), ('banana', 20), ('mango', 10)]
```

or

```
[('orange', 50), ('peach', 20), ('mango', 10)]
```

So only one of the two fruits with the same value would be listed at random.

I am not sure where to implement random.choice to get one of the two fruits of the same value at random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove duplicate values at random from the original dictionary and then sort. Something like this:

```py
import random


def random_top():
    dict1 = {"apple": 50, "banana": 20, "orange": 50, "peach": 20, "mango": 10}

    inverted_dict = {}

    for key, val in dict1.items():
        if val in inverted_dict:
            inverted_dict[val].append(key)
        else:
            inverted_dict[val] = [key]

    # inverted dict now has form {50: ["apple", "orange"], 20: ["banana", "peach"], ,,,}

    new_dict = {}
    for val, key in inverted_dict.items():
        possible_keys = inverted_dict[val] # Get all the fruits that have this value
        random_winner = possible_keys[random.randint(0, len(possible_keys))] # Pick one at random
        new_dict[random_winner] = val # Create a new dict with only the winner and that value

    # Oh btw, you can use a lambda for things like your "test" function
    return sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:3]
```

I think this could be written shorter and perhaps with less memory. Though, I think it works.

Comment: Thanks. I like the idea that you could remove one of the values at random. Or just leave one value at random if there are two or more keys of the same value.

Answer (score 1):

```
from heapq import nlargest
from random import choice

# reverse the dictionary and store items with same count in a list
cnts = {}
for k, v in dict1.items(): 
    cnts.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
cnts
# {50: ['apple', 'orange'], 20: ['banana', 'peach'], 10: ['mango']}

# find the top 3 counts and for each count randomly select an item
[(choice(lst), cnt) for cnt, lst in nlargest(3, cnts.items())]
# [('apple', 50), ('peach', 20), ('mango', 10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
dict1 = {'apple':50,'banana':20,'orange':50,'peach':20,
     'mango':10}
reverse_dict = {  v:k for k,v in dict1.items()}
new_dict = {  v:k for k,v in reverse_dict .items()}
new_dict_sorted = sorted(new_dict.items(), key=lambda k :k[1], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the most approachable answer. Thank you for the dictionary reversing idea.

```
#orignial dictionary
dict1 = {'apple':50,'banana':20,'orange':50,'peach':20,
     'mango':10}

#reversing dict1
inverted_dict = {}
for k, v in dict1.items(): 
    inverted_dict .setdefault(v, []).append(k)

#inverted_dict = {50: ['apple', 'orange'], 20: ['banana', 'peach'], 10: ['mango']}

import random


#Randomly select one of the items
result = {k:random.choice(v) for k,v in inverted_dict.items()}
result
```

The result is at random:

```
{50: 'apple', 20: 'peach', 10: 'mango'}
```

or

```
{50: 'orange', 20: 'peach', 10: 'mango'}
```